# Передача значении переменных в модальное окно

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть страница где выводится список всех пользователей. Так же можно редактировать информацию о пользователе. Необходимо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `Редактировать пользователя` открывалось модальное окно и в инпуты этого окна передавалась информация о пользователе(имя, фамилия и т.д.).

Код:

```
<!-- В цикле перебираем всех пользователей-->
 ...
{
 <td><?= $ps['name'];?></td>
 <td><?= $ps['firstName'];?></td>

 <button class="editUser<?=$ps['id']?>" id="<?=$ps['id'] ?>" value="..."> Редактировать пользователя
 </button>  
}


<!-- Модальное окно куда все нужно передать-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" class="userId" id="">
            <input type="text" class="userName" name="userName" value="">
              ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="">Сохранить изменения</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Скрипт который должен передавать значение в модальное окно!-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function() {

   var id = this.id;
   var userName = $('.editUser' + id).val();


   $('#myModal .userId').data('id', id);
   $('#myModal .userName').data('userName', value);


   $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
});
</script>
```

Почему-то данные не приходят. И везде пусто. Что я делаю не так? Как можно по другому передавать значения переменных в модальное окно ?

Comment: а где должно быть не пусто? вы ведь `data-` атрибут пишите, а не значение поля. Более того, извлекаете данные в `username` а записываете некое `value`. Но вообще подход странный какой-то, не понятно зачем все в кнопку записывать/дублировать, если оно у вас в ячейках таблицы записано

Comment: @teran, А как сделать так чтобы эти данные (имя, фамилия) отображались в поле ввода, т.е. в инпутах. Насколько я понимаю для этого нужно чтобы эти значения находились в `value`

Comment: дак использовать не `.data('id', id)`  а `.val(id)`

Comment: @teran, смог получить `value`. Теперь необходимо из модального окна отправить измененный `value`. Если я его меняю просто в инпуте то ничего не происходит, он как пришел так и остается, ничего не меняется

Comment: а вы ждете что само изменится? надо обработать событие закрытия окна, и аналогичным образом значения инпутов записать в таблицу. Прочитайте хотя бы самые начальные мануалы. Куда проще ведь сначала прочитать  документацию, потратить на это некоторое время и сделать, нежели ковыряться долго и упорно самому, и все равно ничего в итоге не получается.

Comment: @teran, знать бы еще в какую сторону копать. Надеюсь я смог до Вас донести что имел ввиду. Т.е. после нажатия на кнопку `Редактировать пользователя` открывается модальное окно и в инпут с классом `userName` этого окна передается значение (например: `abc`),  сейчас это все работает, но мне необходимо изменить значение этого инпута (например на : `abc123`). Если прописать в инпут  `abc123` то значение этого инпута будет которое мы ему передали при открытии модального окна(т.е. `abc`)

Comment: ну вы открыли окно, из таблицы передали туда значения. теперь они показываются в инпутах. закрыли окно. Исходные значения в таблице не изменились. Снова открываете окно, и снова в инпуты записываются старые значения из таблицы. Вам при закрытии окна надо новые значения инпутов записать в таблицу, откуда вы их изначально брали

Comment: @teran, значения в таблице берутся из бд. В модальном окне мы получаем значение из таблицы  и меняем его, после нажатия на кнопку отправить берем уже измененное значение из инпута и отправляем на сервер ajax запросом. Проблема в получении именного значения, могу получить только то что пришло в модальное окно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем понял по из комментариев в чем дальнейшая проблема, но код ваш должен быть каким то таким

```js
var $editRow = null;

$(".edit").click(function(e){
    $editRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    
    $("#uid").val($editRow.data('user-id'));
    $("#uname").val($editRow.find(".uname").text());
    
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});


$("#save").click(function(){
    $editRow.find(".uname").text( $("#uname").val() );
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
    
//    $.post("some-url.php", { ..... })
//       .done(function(){
            // обновить таблицу, закрыть окно
            // $editRow.find(".uname").text( $("#uname").val() );
            //  $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
//       })
//       .fail(function(){
//          // ничего не делать, ошибка 
//       }) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-hover">
<tr data-user-id="123">
    <td class="uid">123</td>
    <td class="uname">username-123</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr data-user-id="321">
    <td class="uid">321</td>
    <td class="uname">username-321</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="edit">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" class="userId" id="uid">
            <input type="text" class="userName" id="uname" name="userName" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save">Сохранить изменения</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почти то что нужно. Только значение нужно менять не в таблице, а в `.userName`.  Чтобы при нажатии на `Сохранить изменения` мы могли получить значение `var userName = $('.userName').val();`  и передать это значение в бд. У вас сразу меняется значение в таблице, а нужно это значение менять в бд. Т.е. мы получаем значение из таблице в модальное окно. Там его меняем и после этого отправляем на сервер. Надеюсь я все доступно объясняю, если это не так прошу меня понять и простить)

Comment: Сделал вот так и вроде все работает: `$("#save").click(function(){

$editRow.find(".userName").text( $("#uname").val() );

var userId = $('.userName').val();
console.log(userId);

$(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
});`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: прошу прощения. Тут возник такой вопрос, допустим я знаю только `id` пользователя и после нажатия на `id` пользователя должно открываться модальное окно в котором будет вся информация о пользователе. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: @r.mcreal проще всего строку таблицы пометить как `<tr id="user-123">`, тогда зная id, можете получить доступ к нужной строке по `$("tr#user-" + id)`. в моем примере в строке указан атрибут `data-user-id`, как вариант. Ну или, если таблицы нет, то сделать ajax-запрос на сервер для получения данных, после чего запихать их в модальное окно

Answer (score 1):

Сначала ты должен открыть модалку, а потом уже передавать в нее value. И делать это нужно не через `data`, а через `val`

`$('#myModal .userId').val(id);
$('#myModal .userName').data('userName', value);`

Comment: смог получить `value`, спасибо! А как мне теперь при отправки формы получить измененный `value`? Т.е. оно приходит в модальное окно, все нормально отображается, но изменить я его не могу(

Comment: уважаемый, какая разница когда вы впишите данные в форму, до показа или после?